# Share Google Drive files on a Facebook Group?

Tags: google-drive, facebook

When our Facebook group takes part in Zoom calls we record them and save the recordings to Google Drive.

We allow our group members to browse and download these recordings.

Is there a way to display Google Drive links to these  recordings on our Facebook group pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply share a folder via google drive and make it accessible to everyone via a link.

---

#### Walkthrough

1. Open https://drive.google.com
2. right-click on the folder you want to share
3. click on "Get link"
   [image: get link]

---

4. In the dropdown menu change from "Restricted" to "Anyone with the link"
   [image: anyone with link]

---

The link address should now be highlighted in green.
[image: highlighted link]

5. Click on "Copy link" and share it.

---

Keep in mind that depending on the jurisdiction you live in it might possibly be illegal to record other people without their knowledge and distribute these recordings.